# How to use data binding on notification with RemoteViews

Tags: android, data-binding, android-notifications

**Is it possible to use [data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) on custom Android notification layouts?** I'm making a custom Android notification layout using RemoteViews as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41888161/how-to-create-a-custom-notification-layout-in-android).

We usually use data binding on our layouts, but it requires inflating it with

```
DataBindingUtil.inflate(context, R.layout.myLayout, ...)
```

But when using RemoteViews, it isn't generally inflated, its just instantiated as:

```
RemoteViews smallContentView = new RemoteViews(packageName, R.layout.notification);
```

Is there a method of DataBindingUtil or RemoteViews to allow data binding?

Comment: Do you find solution, I'm in same case

Comment: No I didn't. And I concluded that it might be by design: that it isn't possible because once the notification is sent to the system to be displayed, it's no longer owned/run by our app/process, the system owns it.

I think you theoretically COULD implement data binding for notifications (or more specifically, RemoteViews), but if it ever was implemented it would be incredibly inefficient because any data-bound UI updates would still require re-sending the whole notification to the system again.