# Xamarin.Forms Android Project not showing Resource.Layout folder

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin.Forms solution in which inside my Android project I have a custom `BroadcastReceiver`. Inside this class I'm trying to create a custom notification layout using `RemoteViews` which was explained to me using this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41888161/how-to-create-a-custom-notification-layout-in-android/41888224#41888224).

However I am having problems with the construction of this class using the `RemoteViews(Android.Content.Context,Resource.Layout)` constructor. Specifically the `Resource.Layout` portion. When I go into the 'Resources' folder there is only a `Drawable` folder (even when 'Show All Files' is enabled). Which is interesting considering I can access layouts after typing `Resource.Layouts`.

[image: Resource Folder]

Is there a way to get a custom `.xml` id int (or `.axml` if that's the case) to be referenced for this strategy inside the Layout 'folder', or any other way Xamarin does instead that I may not have knowledge of?

Comment: In Xamarin.Android, we usually use `.axml` as a layout file.  Are you using Visual Studio? Could you please post a screenshot of your Resource folder?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio 2015? Could you please post your `Resource.Designer.cs` code?

Comment: Any specific part cause it is extremely long? @YorkShen

Comment: When you write a `xx.axml` file, it will register a resource Id in your `Resource.Designer.cs`, so that you could find the `xx.axml` when you use `Resource.Layout`. This work usually did by visual studio, if not, you cant find it as your question.

Comment: Anytime I make an `.axml` or `.xml` file anywhere inside the Android project of my Xamarin.Forms solution it brings up the same error and breaks  the build.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Yes, I have VS 2017 too but I've been using 2015

Comment: This usually happens in vs 2015, you could use vs 2017 and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially all you have to do is add a folder in the Android project named "Layout" under the `Resources` folder. Then create the `.axml` file. Then the file can be referenced using `Resources.Layout` and the id retrieved using the method from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41888161/how-to-create-a-custom-notification-layout-in-android?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: The link to the thread you posted might be wrong.