# How to have a slideshow of images inside a notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

I recently saw a notification with BigPicture style which had multiple images shown as a slideshow.

Are viewpagers allowed inside RemoteViews now?

If not can anyone tell me how they managed to show a slideshow of images inside a notification. This seems like a really cool feature.

I am attaching the image that i captured and it shows a view pager indicator style dots. There are three images which keep rotating.

Please guide me as to how to achieve this
[image: notification with slideshow of 3 images]

Comment: Why the down vote, it's a genuine question and i can't find a solution anywhere.

Comment: did you get the answer ?

Comment: Nope, no answers... Gave up on it finally

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom notification layout and put your slideshow view there. This is answered here: [How to create a Custom Notification Layout in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41888161/how-to-create-a-custom-notification-layout-in-android)

Comment: I know how to make a remote view... As i said, they have a slideshow of images with a pager indicator which afaik isn't allowed inside a remote view. So how to achieve that