# Android Notifications: how to include extra text in top line

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

These are 2 notifications on Android 7+:

- in the top line, this one presents: the **icon**, the **app name**, and the **time**
  [image]

- in the top line, this one presents: the **icon**, the **app name**, an **extra text** (in the case of Gmail is the account email address), and the **time**
  [image]

Can anyone explain how to include the **extra text** between the app name and the notification time, as shown in the Gmail notification?

Is there a method of `NotificationCompat.Builder` to set that text?

```
   NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NotificationChannels.TRIPS_CHANNEL_ID)
      .setSmallIcon(ICON_DRAWABLE)
      .setColor(TITLE_COLOR)
      .setContentTitle(FIRST_LINE_TEXT) // "Remote input"
      .setContentText(SECOND_LINE_TEXT); // "Try typing some text!"
```

Comment: can the person that just downvoted give an explanation, please?

Comment: Wasn't me but I assume that they felt you did not perform a minimal on self research on this subject. You posted no code showing that you have attempted to solve the "problem" yourself.

Comment: @Barns I have included some code. Let's see if that helps.

Comment: @Barns can you help me by upvoting the question? thanks!

Comment: So you have try the above code (which isn't quite complete -- how is the notification being posted?) what is the result you are seeing? Is the "FIRST_LINE_TEXT" and/or "SECOND_LINE_TEXT" not being displayed?

Comment: I have just included the code concerning the UI

Comment: Sorry my Solution didn't help you on your problem. I guess it just isn't clear to me exactly what you are expecting-- Good luck finding the right solution. You will probably have better luck getting a response if I remove my suggestion.

Comment: @Barns I have updated my question, to clarify what I mean

Comment: Maybe take a look at the most popular answer from this post using `RemoteView` :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41888161/how-to-create-a-custom-notification-layout-in-android

Comment: @Barns actually one of the answers there gave me the hint! It is `setSubText()`!!!

Answer (score 8):

Found the answer!

It's the subtext:

`.setSubText("text to show next to app name")`

Comment: would be nice if Google added this to their guide https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications