# Notifications: how to change text color and background?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-remoteview

On Android 7 and following,

I would like to:

- change the color of the notification text
- change the background of the notification (using a light color, or a drawable)
- still keep the standard header and action buttons (so I don't want to use an entirely custom notification)

I read that `DecoratedCustomViewStyle()` allows to

> customize notification views and still obtain system decorations like
>   notification headers, actions, and expandable layouts

Any suggestion on how to achieve a simple notification with the points stated above?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41888224/4824088 & also here [Android Custom Notification](http://code.hootsuite.com/custom-notifications-for-android/)