# How to show notification with play/stop button?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-notifications

I need some help as I am a bit new in android. In my android app that I am working on, I have implemented MediaPlayer service class (PlayService.java) which will play live radio audio stream from a remote source. My working code for MediaPlayer Service class is:

```
public class PlayService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener,MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener,MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener,MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener,AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener  {

    private AudioManager audioManager;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    private String sentAudioLink;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        sentAudioLink = intent.getExtras().getString("sentAudioLink");
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        //setup the media player data source using the strAudioLink value
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(sentAudioLink);
                //prepare media player
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.e("workingerror1", e.toString());
                stopSelf();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                Log.e("workingerror2", e.toString());
                stopSelf();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("workingerror3", e.toString());
                stopSelf();
            }

            //buildNotification(PlaybackStatus.PLAYING);
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        stopMedia();
        stopSelf();
    }

    public void stopMedia() {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            mediaPlayer.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        //Invoked when there has been an error during an asynchronous operation
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        playMedia();
    }

    public void playMedia() {
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The only problem that I face is I just want that music player will generate a custom notification when the audio stream is playing. And for that purpose, I have created custom_notification.xml class. I don't know that how should I create this custom notification from service and trigger call listeners for play and stop action button.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="4dp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:src="@drawable/uow_logo"
        android:id="@+id/imgAppIc" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgAppIc"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/selected_track_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title Text"
            android:textColor="#f7212121"
            android:textSize="15dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/selected_track_title2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FM Radio 100"
            android:textColor="#767676"
            android:layout_below="@+id/selected_track_title"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/play_pause"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: look at notificationBuilder (step 5) on https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-music-player/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fio2018#0

Answer (score 1):

This Answer May Helps You...

Ref: [How to create a Custom Notification Layout in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41888161/how-to-create-a-custom-notification-layout-in-android)

> To define a custom notification layout, start by instantiating a RemoteViews object that inflates an XML layout file. Then, instead of
>   calling methods such as setContentTitle(), call setContent(). To set
>   content details in the custom notification, use the methods in 
>   RemoteViews to set the values of the view's children:
>
> Create an XML layout for the notification in a separate file. You can
>   use any file name you wish, but you must use the extension .xml In
>   your app, use RemoteViews methods to define your notification's icons
>   and text. Put this RemoteViews object into your 
>   NotificationCompat.Builder by calling setContent(). Avoid setting a
>   background Drawable on your RemoteViews object, because your text
>   color may become unreadable.

custom_push.xml has my custom views R.id.image,R.id.text,R.id.title

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:padding="10dp" >
    <ImageView
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="Testing"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
        />
    <TextView
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="Testing is awecome"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Instantiating a RemoteViews object and set it,

```
RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_push);
contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, "Custom notification");
contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, "This is a custom layout");

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
.setContent(contentView);

Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

[image: Notification Views Like]

check : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#ApplyStyle