# How can I change properties of a view in remoteviews?

Tags: android

I'm coding a widget for the first time and I have an instance of `RemoteViews` that contains a `LinearLayout` with the id `R.id.linear_layout`. At some point I need to change the orientation of that `LinearLayout` (inside the `onUpdate` method of my `AppWidgetProvider`). How can I do that?

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.widget_layout);
// change the orientaion of the linearLayout
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
```

Comment: Find id of your root element in layout and try to set orientation on it

Comment: and how do i do that? can you tell me the function i have to use?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41888161/how-to-create-a-custom-notification-layout-in-android

Answer (score 0):

RemoteViews won't let you modify the actual `orientation` property. Two potential work-arounds:

**Approach #1**

Use the constructor for that purpose: [RemoteViews(RemoteViews landscape, RemoteViews portrait)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#RemoteViews(android.widget.RemoteViews,%20android.widget.RemoteViews))

**Approach #2**

In your main layout file, include both a horizontal and a vertical `LinearLayout`, both of which carry the same information (they have identical children). Then, selectively display one or the other:

```
if( useVertical )
{
    remoteViews.setViewVisibility( R.id.linear_lyout_horizontal, View.GONE );
    remoteViews.setViewVisibility( R.id.linear_lyout_vertical, View.VISIBLE );
}
```