# how to change the notification button text to lowercase in android?

Tags: android, android-notifications

Is it possible to change the text style and convert into lowercase? Why does android is not giving such functionality like that?

**Code:**

```
builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, id);
            editIntent = new Intent(context, ReminderDetailActivity.class);
            editIntent.putExtra(REMINDER_ID, mReceivedId);
            editIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, rowId, editIntent, 0);
            builder.setContentTitle(mTitle)

                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                    .setContentTitle(mTitle)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alarm_black_24dp)
                    .setSound(mUri)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_icon_alarm, context.getString(R.string.pay_now), pendingIntent)
                    .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_REMINDER)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText("Have you completed your task?"))
                    .setBadgeIconType(NotificationCompat.BADGE_ICON_LARGE)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);

            builder.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));
```

Comment: Have you heard about RemoteViews ?

Comment: @MalavanRockzz Nope. Please guide me

Comment: For more customization, you've to use RemoteView as the content of notification, 
Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41888161/how-to-create-a-custom-notification-layout-in-android

Comment: Let me know to write an elaborate answer to this if you really need it.

Comment: @MalavanRockzz let me check